# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed still not knowing what goes wrong

Tags: c#, try-catch, reader

I looked around on stackoverflow but i can't really find the answer.
Maybe I'm overlooking it. 
This is my code. after the first while it keeps going back to the while loop
and after I close the reader it goes back to while(reader.read())

```
   public string VoegHoeveelheidToe(string HandmatigHoeveelheid, string ControleerBarcode)
      {
            string i = null;
            int Beginhoeveelheid;
            int ToeTeVoegenHoeveelheid;
            ToeTeVoegenHoeveelheid = Convert.ToInt32(HandmatigHoeveelheid);
            try
            {
                connectie.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = null;
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT hoeveelheid from Voorraad,Product Where Voorraad.Barcode = Product.Barcode AND Voorraad.Barcode = '" + ControleerBarcode + "'", connectie);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Beginhoeveelheid = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    ToeTeVoegenHoeveelheid = Beginhoeveelheid + Convert.ToInt32(HandmatigHoeveelheid);
                    if(ToeTeVoegenHoeveelheid < Beginhoeveelheid)
                    {
                        i = Convert.ToString(3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connectie.Close();
                        try
                        {
                            connectie.Open();
                            OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
                            command1.Connection = connectie;
                            string query = "Update Voorraad set hoeveelheid = " + ToeTeVoegenHoeveelheid + " Where barcode='" + ControleerBarcode + "'";
                            command1.CommandText = query;
                            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            i = Convert.ToString(1);
                            connectie.Close();                                
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            i = Convert.ToString(2);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception )
            {
                i = Convert.ToString(2);
            }
            connectie.Close(); return i;
```

Comment: I don't understand this _after the first while it keeps going back to the while loop_. Isn't that how `while` statement works already?

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the connection inside the `while`. This will implicitly close any readers, hence the error. Basically: don't do that. I strongly suggest adding `using` statements instead of closing and `try`/`catch`,`finally`, and to break out of a loop: `break`.

I am not sure why you have the `connectie.Close();` inside the loop; perhaps you added that because of the "multiple active readers on a connection" issue. If this is the case, you will need to buffer information about what you want to do during the first reader, and only execute the pending commands when the reader is finished. Or use multiple connections.

Comment: @Qun: I agree with Marc's observations about the specific error here. However, the code also seems broken in other ways. Most notably: `if(ToeTeVoegenHoeveelheid < Beginhoeveelheid)`, which is testing an invariant condition for the method, i.e. the outcome of the comparison relies entirely on the value of  `HandmatigHoeveelheid` which never changes during the method. It is also odd that `HandmatigHoeveelheid` isn't just converted to an `int` once (or passed as one!), and that you ask .NET to convert `int` literals to `string` instances (for `i`), when a `string` literal would work just as well